# Cannot access method within a static context

Tags: inheritance, methods, static-methods

I'm a fairly novice high school programmer and I'm finishing up my last projects on inheritance for school.  I have a project called "Worker" which is really stumping me.  I need to be able to print out everything but I can't seem to print out what I need to without either getting no print out or getting the "cannot access method within a static context error."  Here is the code for the super class called worker:

```
package mod6;

public class Worker {

   public Worker(double wage, String name) {
       private double hours; // I GET AN ERROR HERE that says "illegal start of expression"
       private double wage;
       private int rate;
       private String name;


   public double computePay(int hours) {
       return hours * rate;
   }

   public String getName(String name) {  
       String temp[] = name.split("\\s");
       char initial = temp[0].charAt(0);
       String lname = temp[1];
       return name = (lname + ", " + initial + ".");
   }
}
```

EDIT: the only problem I now have is the error in line 7 of the worker class above.
And here is the code for the WorkerTester class that I don't currently get a correct output from:

```
package mod6;

public class WorkerTester extends Worker {

  public WorkerTester(double wage, String name, int hours) {
      super(wage, name); 
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {
  System.out.println("Type" + "\t" + "Name" + "\t" + "Wage" + "\t" + "Hours" + "\t" + "Number of Pieces" + "Income"); } //**Nothing prints out below this line**
  public void TestHourly() {
      HourlyWorker John = new HourlyWorker(9.48, "John Doe", 43);
      System.out.print("Hourly" + "\t" + getName("John Doe")  + "\t" + "9.48" + "\t" + "43" + "\t" + "n/a" + "\t" + John.Wage());
  }
  public void TestSalaried() {
      SalariedWorker Karen = new SalariedWorker(25.79, "Karen Jones", 52);
      System.out.println("Salaried" + "\t" + getName("Karen Jones")  + "\t" + "25.76" + "\t" + "52" + "\t" + "n/a" + "\t" + Karen.Wage());
  }
  public void TestPiece() {
      SalariedWorker Wesley = new SalariedWorker(5.65, "Wesley Smith", 36);
      System.out.println("Piece" + "\t" + getName("Wesley Smith")  + "\t" + "5.65" + "\t" + "36" + "\t" + "1025" + "\t" + Wesley.Wage());
  }
}
```

It's likely an easy fix, I just can't figure it out with my limited programming knowledge and I'm out of ideas for rearranging the code.  Also, the coding could be very wrong (remember I'm new to this) so please keep that in mind.  If someone could help me out in fixing this code to print out properly, that'd be great! Thanks.

Here is the SalariedWorker class for reference:

public class SalariedWorker extends Worker {

```
public SalariedWorker(double wage, String name, int hours) {

    super(wage, name);

}

public double Wage() {

    return computePay(40);

}
```

}

Comment: You are not printing because you never invoke the sub methods in your main method. You are getting the static error because you are invoking a method without an instance. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring additional methods in your main method that you are not invoking. Remove the methods and just instantiate, initialize, and print all of your workers inside the main method.

Also, you are invoking getName without an instance of worker. You need something like this.

```
Worker worker = new Worker(//pass your parameter);
worker.getName();
```

Honestly, you are using the getter method incorrectly an appropriate getter should return the private variable or a small manipulation of it, not edit the parameter that you pass it.

This is a better getter:

```
public String getName() {  
   String temp[] = name.split("\\s");
   char initial = temp[0].charAt(0);
   String lname = temp[1];
   return (lname + ", " + initial + ".");
}
```

This way you refer to the instance variable name that is private and not the parameter "name" that you originally pass into your method

Comment: I used methods because it was required in the assignment.  Which wasn't logical to me, but nevertheless the were required.  But thanks for the tip with making the worker object to bring it into the main method.  I'll give it a shot. EDIT: I got the errors removed for the workertester class, thanks a ton.  But it still will not print correctly because of the error in line 7 of the worker class.  Do you have any tips for that error?

Comment: @noviceprogrammer It appears you are missing a brace and not properly closing your constructor in the worker class. Also, if you are passing in variables to the constructor you should set the equal to your instance variables. Declare all of your private variables before the constructor then set the two variables you pass equal to your instance variables like this.wage = wage;

Comment: thanks a ton! You've been a lot of help, and it's printing right now.  Except it isn't.  The income part of the workertester (such as Karen.Wage();) wont print correctly.  It prints as a 0.0.  I'll put the salaried worker class in the question for reference.

Comment: @noviceprogrammer I can't see your SalariedWorker class. I suspect you are not correctly initializing the wage and it is maintaining its default value of zero. It also could be another problem with your getter where you are shadowing the instance variable with your parameter variable. Judging from your main method, I don't think you are correctly applying the concepts of inheritance. You should refer to [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) Also, if this post has helped you, can you please upvote it and mark it as the correct answer. Thank You

Comment: I put the SalariedWorker class up in the question at the bottom.  I think you're right about the incorrect initializing though.  Also, I think I understand the concept behind inheritance I'm just having trouble putting the pieces together.  Lastly, I sadly cannot upvote it because I do not have 15 reputation.  But it will be marked as correct.

Comment: Its because rate is never initialized, so it has a default value of zero. Neither you Worker, nor your SalaryWorker class ever initializes rate

Comment: I understand that now, but I don't know where to intialize it. I've been fiddling around with it and I can't get the correct value to output.

Comment: @noviceprogrammer you should remove the variables wage and rate from the Worker class as wage applies to SalariedWorker and rate applies to HourlyWorker. Each, subclass should have their own implementation of computePay(). You initialize these variables in the constructors or via a setter method. public SalaryWorker(int wage) {this.wage = wage;}

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Honestly, I can code it that way, and fairly easily.  It's just that the problem was worded very strangely and I've been trying to code the project based on that. I guess I'll just screw it and do it your way. :) thanks!